# Regarding installing gazebo simulator

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while installing Gazebo simulator in ROS electric,this statement is given on Gazebo wiki page,ROS Users: Never install gazebo from here. Use these instructions. ,and when we click on the folowing link,it direct us to ROS installation page where no information is being given for the installation of Gazebo simulator,Kindly help me to overcome this situation.........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34822/regarding-installing-gazebo-simulator/) by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-25**:
edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
If you have installed the ros-electric-desktop-full then gazebo comes along with it.
You just have to follow the instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo) and get started.

If you have installed ros by other means and don't get gazebo along with it. Then checkout the stack from as given in the [link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) controlled by svn and compile the package and follow the instructions in the first link of this answer.

Let me know if any issues.

Hope it helps,

Karthik

---

As you are not sure about your installation you may face dependencies issues later on. I suggest you to reinstall ROS desktop full version and get the Gazebo. Else you have to download the stack of Gazebo from the subversion using

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo ~/ros_workspace/gazebo
```

followed by

```
cd ~/ros_workspace
rospack profile
rosmake gazebo
```

If you get any errors mostly would be for the dependencies which you may have to install individually till you get the gazebo package compiled successfully.
Hope it helps.

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on 2012-05-25**:
hey kartik, after going through your instruction to instal gazebo,it was being installed but with a warning.

**Comment by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on 2012-05-25**:
hey kartik,